# How to output a relational object using Linq on View models in Entity Framework Core

Tags: linq, asp.net-web-api, view, entity-framework-core

I have some views in a SQL database with a structure similar to what is shown below. I’ve simplified the views to get my question across.

[image]

I'm using Entity Framework Core in a Web API solution. The DTO classes that are generated from the views are below (no relationship in the view models)

```
Public Class VW_Customer
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

Public Class VW_Order
{
    public int Customer_id { get; set; }
    public string Item { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

My API response object model is like this (with relationship)

```
Public Class OrderReport
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Order> orders { get; set; }
}

Public Class Order
{
    public string item  { get; set; }
    public decimal price{ get; set; }
}
```

How do I write a Linq query to get the API response looking like this:

```
[
    {
        "id ": 1,
        "name ": "John",
        "orders": [
            {
                "item": "Bread",
                "price": 0.9
            },
            {
                "item": "Flour",
                "price": 1.2
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id ": 2,
        "name ": "Tom",
        "orders": [
            {
                "item": "Buter",
                "price": 1.5
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to create custom projection

```cs
var query = 
  from c in db.VW_Customer
  select new OrderReport
  {
     id = c.id,
     name = c.name
     orders = db.VW_Order.Where(o => o.Customer_id == c.id)
        .Select(o => new Order
        {
           item = o.Item,
           price = o.Price
        })
        .ToArray()
  };

var result = query.ToArray();
```

**Update**

If there is no chance to make it work, since EF Core for eager loading needs entities with keys. You can use client-side combining.

```cs
var customers = db.VW_Customer.ToList();
var orders = db.VW_Order.ToList();

var query =
  from c in customers
  join o in orders on c.id equals o.Customer_id into g 
  select new OrderReport
  {
     id = c.id,
     name = c.name
     orders = g.Select(o => new Order
              {
                 item = o.Item,
                 price = o.Price
              })
             .ToArray()
  };

var result = query.ToArray();
```

Comment: in my solution (not the simplified version above) im getting " Unable to translate collection subquery in projection since the parent query doesn't project key columns of all of it's tables which are required to generate results on client side. This can happen when trying to correlate on keyless entity or when using 'Distinct' or 'GroupBy' operations without projecting all of the key columns."

Comment: So, then you have to combine two queries on the client side. Looks like EF’s Eager Loading can not handle keyless entities. Will update answer.

Comment: Thanks @Svyatoslav. Is the reason i was getting the error was because im reading from Views and not tables?

Comment: Try to define keys for your entities `VW_Customer (Id)`, `VW_Order(Customer_id, Item)`, probably it should start work.

Comment: Regarding Update: Not sure what do you mean by "client-side combining", but lol, they don't support `GroupJoin` (`join into`) at all (except for weird LINQ left join pattern), and not willing to, regardless of the arguments - see https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/17068 and https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/19930. So the updated variant will simply fail at runtime, while the original with correlated subquery at least has some chances.

Comment: @IvanStoev, just finalized result using LINQ to objects. About EF Core, what can I say, they are still on the start, I can kill translation with common sense queries with ease. GroupJoin translation is another heavy part. It works in `linq2db` and I'm happy ;)

Comment: @Svyatoslav Good for you! But this make me laugh: "Still on the start", hah - EFC1.0 has been officially released  June 2016, and probably was in development since 2013-2014 :)

Comment: @IvanStoev, you have to start counting from EF Core 3.0. They have rewritten translator completely (without relinq) and I think it is not latest reincarnation.

Answer (score 0):

I found out in order to use Eager Loading (first solution by @Svyatoslav) I had to make few adjustments.

*Note: If you are doing DB First and you regenerate the model all changes will be lost*

I had to explicitly set the key property in the Model with the ["Key"] attribute

```
Public Class VW_Customer
{   [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

Public Class VW_Order
{
    public int Customer_id { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public int Oder_id{ get; set; }
    public string Item { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

I then had to change the DBContet Class to specify that the VW_Customer and VW-Order had Alternative keys. To do this i remove this line for both entities

```
 entity.HasNoKey();
```

and replace it with

```
      modelBuilder.Entity<VW_Customer>(entity =>
            {
               entity.HasAlternateKey(x => x.Id);
               ......


      modelBuilder.Entity<VW_Order>(entity =>
            {
               entity.HasAlternateKey(x => x.Order_Id);
               ......
```

After doing that i was able to generate the desired output based on Svyatoslav first solution.
The problem with this approach is that if the model is regenerated from the DB then all the changes made above will be lost.

If there is a clever way of preventing these changes from being overwritten (after regenerating the model from the DB) please suggest it as it could be helpful.